# Field Extension $E/F$ algebraic iff every subring $R$ of $E$ which contains $F$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $E/F$ be a field extension and $F\subset R\subset E$ where $R$ is a subring of $E$. I want to show that: $E/F$ is algebraic iff every subring $R$ of $E$ which contains $F$ is a field.

I already proved that if $E/F$ is algebraic then $R$ is a field. (Note that $R$ is completely arbitrary).

Now I am stuck at the converse, namely, if for every subring $R$ it holds that it is a field ($R$ given as above), then $E/F$ is algebraic.

My strategy would be that I choose an arbitrary $r\in R$ and look at $F[r]=F(r)$ where I have used that every subring is a field. But now I have trouble proceeding, because I can not work with finite polynomials to show anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is not an algebraic extension of $F$, then there's some $\omega\in E$ which is transcendental over $F$. Take $R=F[\omega]$. It is a ring, but not a field ($\omega$ has no inverse there).

Comment: Could you elaborate why $\omega$ can not have an inverse?

Comment: Because $\frac1\omega$ would be an element of $F[\omega]$. In other words, $\frac1\omega=P(\omega)$, for some $P(x)\in F[x]$. But then $\omega$ would be root of $xP(x)-1$. This is impossible, since $\omega$ is transcendental over $F$.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way of showing that $E/F$ is algebraic, without using contradiction, e.g. constructing a minimal polynomial for $r$, using $F(r)$?

Comment: If I find one, I will tell you. But I find my approach a natural one.